# Datagridview row selected despite ClearSelection

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Form with a datagridview which has rows in it which by default I leave unselected. The reason for this is that there is a download button, which I want to be activated only once the user selects a row.

I have written the `PopulateDataGridView` function as below :

```
 private async Task PopulateDataGridView()
        {
            dataGridView_MyObjects.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView_MyObjects.Refresh();
            
            try
            {
                --- code to populate the rows ----

                dataGridView_MyObjects.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView_MyObjects.Refresh();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                CSMessageBox.Show("Cannot retreive the data right now. Please try Later");
            }
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that during one session of the application, when I launch the form the first time, no row is selected, which is the expected behavior. But when I launch the form again after closing it, the first row shows up as selected or atleast highlighted which makes the user thinks that row is already selected but the download button remains inactive.

I am not sure if there is another piece of code I may be missing to make sure every time the `PopulateDataGridView` function is called, there is no row selected. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: how do you create and launch the form at 1st time and 2nd time?

Comment: thank you for your reply @VietDD. The same formload function launches the form both the times. It seems I have figured out how to clear the selection though. The clearSelection needs to come in the formLoad function itself. Once I moved it there, the form works as expected

Comment: okay, so not need to do anything more .